Sequence capability for Robotic Arm with OMPL and Move Group Python Interface
I'm using ROS Noetic and specifically MoveIt Move Group Python Interface to perform some movements with a robotic arm for palletizing purposes. In the environment, there are various static obstacles that the arm needs to avoid while moving. So far, I've been using the OMPL library, specifically the RRTConnect algorithm, which works almost flawlessly. The robotic arm executes the pick and place process without any serious issues. That is, it moves from point A to point C smoothly.
However, after the pick process (point A), the arm will move to point B (slightly above the pallet) to avoid other objects on the pallet. To go from point B to point C, the corresponding motion needs to be redesigned to avoid obstacles until reaching the final destination.
Is there a way to unify trajectories A-B and B-C to eliminate the delay of interrupting the movement and finding a new plan for the algorithm?
I read that something similar can be done with PILZ (sequence capability); however, because there are obstacles in the space, the trajectories are invalidated, and the movements are not executed.
